# Changing height of an UI panel using Array content

Tags: c#, unity3d

I've created following code which works just fine:

```
GraphBar1.GetComponent<RectTransform> ().sizeDelta = new Vector2 (50, oScript.reactionTimeArray [0] * 1000);
GraphBar2.GetComponent<RectTransform> ().sizeDelta = new Vector2 (50, oScript.reactionTimeArray [1] * 1000);
GraphBar3.GetComponent<RectTransform> ().sizeDelta = new Vector2 (50, oScript.reactionTimeArray [2] * 1000);
GraphBar4.GetComponent<RectTransform> ().sizeDelta = new Vector2 (50, oScript.reactionTimeArray [3] * 1000);
GraphBar5.GetComponent<RectTransform> ().sizeDelta = new Vector2 (50, oScript.reactionTimeArray [4] * 1000);
GraphBar6.GetComponent<RectTransform> ().sizeDelta = new Vector2 (50, oScript.reactionTimeArray [5] * 1000);
GraphBar7.GetComponent<RectTransform> ().sizeDelta = new Vector2 (50, oScript.reactionTimeArray [6] * 1000);
GraphBar8.GetComponent<RectTransform> ().sizeDelta = new Vector2 (50, oScript.reactionTimeArray [7] * 1000);
GraphBar9.GetComponent<RectTransform> ().sizeDelta = new Vector2 (50, oScript.reactionTimeArray [8] * 1000);
GraphBar10.GetComponent<RectTransform> ().sizeDelta = new Vector2 (50, oScript.reactionTimeArray [9] * 1000);
```

As I'm re-writing almost the same code so many times, I'm convinced this can be done using less code, even though I'm confused on how to do it with the Array properties being present.

Comment: As we all want to make our code more efficient or improve it in one way or another, **try to write a title that summarizes what your code does**, not what you want to get out of a review. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/2438/41243) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: Can you do a loop through the graphbars and refactor it to a single function? Sorry, I don't know this language.

Comment: @Raystafarian This is kinda the way I thought to do it - however I fail to do it, and thats where I would like the assistance =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be written as :

```
var graphBars = new[] { GraphBar1, GraphBar2, GraphBar3, GraphBar4, GraphBar5, GraphBar6, GraphBar7, GraphBar8, GraphBar9, GraphBar10 };
for (int i = 0; i < graphBars.Length; i++)
    graphBars[i].GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta =
        new Vector2(50, oScript.reactionTimeArray[i] * 1000);
```